# Zend Framework: Update query

Tags: zend-framework

That is my update function:

```
$id = 5; $points = 100;

public function update($id, $points) {
    $this->update(array('points = ?' => new Zend_DB_Expr('points + 1')), array('id = ?' => $id));
}
```

But, when I call this function an occurs error:

> **SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

Comment: Just check this link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679770/zf-invalid-parameter-number-no-parameters-were-bound-error> may be u will get the answer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should have been

```
$this->update (array (
    'points' => new Zend_DB_Expr ('points + 1') 
), array (
    'id = ?' => $id 
));
```