# counting particular rows in a table in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, echo

I am trying to count rows in a table that match a particular column called `cat_id`. I'm stuck getting this error:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
public function getNoJobs($id)
{
    $select=$this->_db->select();
    $select->from('job','COUNT(id)');
    $select->where('cat_id=?',$id);
    $result=$this->getAdapter()->fetchAll($select);
    return $result;
}
```

I call this from an action called `index`. The `$result` is the `cat_id` i get from a form:

```
$result=$this->_request->getParam('category');
$validate=new Application_Model_DbTable_Procedure();
$job=$validate->getNoJobs($result);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add a zend tag, please?

Comment: @EngineerDollery Any idea if that was the correct tag?

Comment: This is most probably because `$id` is null or undefined.

Comment: After : $select->where('cat_id=?', $id); , try die($select->__toString()); you will see if you have a valid SQL query.

Comment: your category parameter value is empty. post the uri here.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it is that `$id` is `NULL` as @sbooob suggested.

This question and *Why you should always validate your data in every function especially in models* are answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6679842/840409

What I would like to add as a tool is a live "on-site" debugger like [ZFDebug](https://github.com/jokkedk/ZFDebug) if you've had it on you'd most probably already seen the answer for your self since you'd be able to monitor all the generated queries. I strongly encourage using such tools.