# Update of user data causes PDO exception

Tags: php, pdo

It doesn't update the data it keeps giving me an error. If the email already exist, it should tell me email exist but it can not update user data.

It give me this error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in C:\xampp\htdocs\php.dev\classes\Model.php on line 37

**classed/Model.php**

```
abstract class Model {
    protected $dbh;
    protected $stmt;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOST.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
    }

    // binds the prepare statement
    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;

                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }
        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute() {
        $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function resultSet() {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function lastInsertId() {
        return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function emailExist() {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}
```

**controllers/users.php**

```
class Users extends Controller{
    protected function profile(){
        if (!isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) {//if user do not login they can not profile page
            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL.'shares');
        }
        $viewmodel = new UserModel();
        $this->returnView($viewmodel->profile(), true);
    }

    protected function register(){
        if (isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) {//if user do not logout they can not access register page
            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL.'shares');
        }
        $viewmodel = new UserModel();
        $this->returnView($viewmodel->register(), true);
    }

    protected function login(){
        if (isset($_SESSION['is_logged_in'])) {//if user do not logout they can not access login page
            header('Location: '.ROOT_URL.'shares');
        }
        $viewmodel = new UserModel();
        $this->returnView($viewmodel->login(), true);
    }

    protected function logout(){
        unset($_SESSION['is_logged_in']);
        unset($_SESSION['user_data']);
        session_destroy();
        // Redirect
        header('Location: '.ROOT_URL);
    }
}
```

**models/user.php**

```
class UserModel extends Model {

    public function profile() {
        // Sanitize POST
        $post = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

        if($post['updateProfile']) {
            #$name = $post['name'];
            #$email = $post['email'];
            #$id = $post['id'];

            if (empty($post['name']) || empty($post['email'])) {
                Messages::setMsg('Please Fill All Form Fields', 'error');
                return;
            }

            // check if email is already taken
            $this->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
            $this->bind(':email', $post['email']);
            $row = $this->emailExist();
            if ($row) {
                Messages::setMsg('Email already Exist', 'error');
                return;
            } else {
                # Update the MySQL
                $this->query("UPDATE users SET name =:name, email =:email WHERE id =:id");

                $this->execute();
                // Verify
                if($this->lastInsertId()){
                    Messages::setMsg('Successfull Updated', 'success');
                    return;
                } else {
                    Messages::setMsg('Error while updating data', 'error');
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

**view/users/profile.php**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
       <h3 class="panel-title">Update Data</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_data']['name'];?>" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_data']['email'];?>" />

                <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" value="" />
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" name="updateProfile" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As the error message says, you are not binding the parameters for the update query.

Comment: please can u give me example about that l mean ideas      @Peter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ZF: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679770/zf-invalid-parameter-number-no-parameters-were-bound-error)

Answer (score 0):

Your class function execute() needs to accept array values for the bound parameters in your sql string.

**In classed/Model.php change:**

```
public function execute() {
    $this->stmt->execute();
}
```

**To:**

```
public function execute($params=NULL) {
    $this->stmt->execute($params);
}
```

You are not binding variables to the specified variable names in your sql string.

**models/user.php - Replace:**

```
$this->execute();
```

**With:**

```
$this->execute(array(':name' => $post['name'], ':email' => $post['email'], ':id'=>$post['id']));
```

Comment: It still not working it keep on giving me error while updating data

Comment: Can you pastebin both updated - `classed/Model.php` and `models/user.php` ?

Comment: so please what should l do there

Comment: Post the codes in `New Paste` field >> Scroll Down >> Click `Create New Paste`

Comment: Copy Paste the URL to here.

Comment: I SHOULD COPY BOTH classes/Model.php and models/user.php

Comment: i don't get it ?

Comment: You posted the code on pastebin? Can you post the link here?

Comment: have you seen it @Kario

Comment: It looks fine to me. I think that's the best I can do to help. :D

Comment: can you give me your email so l sent the code to you please

Comment: What's your email? I'll email you.

Comment: my email si si si

Comment: Thanks. Sent you an email.

Comment: Sent u an email.